# how to accept custom oauth2 and oidc authentication server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I had been made a custom auth server wiht `org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:1.2.2` and `spring boot 3.x`.

And I tried to make a server like documents.

but there was a problem.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityCon {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain( HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer( OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc( oidc -> oidc
                        .providerConfigurationEndpoint( provider -> provider
                                .providerConfigurationCustomizer( config->config
                                        .issuer( "http://localhost:8000" )
                                        .userInfoEndpoint( "/user" )
                                        .authorizationEndpoint( "/login/oauth2/oidc-client" ) ) )
                        .userInfoEndpoint( userinfo -> userinfo.authenticationProvider( new AuthenticationProvider() {
                    @Override
                    public Authentication authenticate( Authentication authentication ) throws AuthenticationException {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean supports( Class< ? > authentication ) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } ) )); // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .csrf( httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable());
                // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
                // authorization server filter chain
//              .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("user")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId( UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("oidc-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .scope( OidcScopes.OPENID )
//              .clientAuthenticationMethod( ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType( AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/oauth2/code/oidc-client")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8000/")

                .clientSettings( ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource< SecurityContext > jwkSource() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder( JWKSource< SecurityContext > jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }

}
```

I made a configuration.

And I called `http://localhost:8000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=oidc-client&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/oauth2/code/oidc-client`
url with GET Method.

but Spring occurred error and this is my debug log.

```
2024-03-13T14:50:18.625+09:00 DEBUG 77476 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=oidc-client&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/oauth2/code/oidc-client
2024-03-13T14:50:18.626+09:00 DEBUG 77476 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-03-13T14:50:18.629+09:00 DEBUG 77476 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=oidc-client&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/oauth2/code/oidc-client&continue to session
2024-03-13T14:50:18.629+09:00 DEBUG 77476 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using Or [Ant [pattern='/oauth2/token', POST], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/introspect', POST], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/revoke', POST], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/device_authorization', POST]]
2024-03-13T14:50:18.629+09:00 DEBUG 77476 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using Or [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer$BearerTokenRequestMatcher@74a820bf, RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest], And [Not [MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@2dafae61, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@2dafae61, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@2dafae61, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]]
2024-03-13T14:50:18.631+09:00 DEBUG 77476 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint@1060c298
```

I tested one more things.

did Oidc auth endpoint work well??

so I called http://localhost:8000/login/oauth2/oidc-client.
but spring give me a 404 error.

why didn't accept oidc custom config??

i apparently set custom config like this.

```
http.getConfigurer( OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc( oidc -> oidc
                        .providerConfigurationEndpoint( provider -> provider
                                .providerConfigurationCustomizer( config->config
                                        .issuer( "http://localhost:8000" )
                                        .userInfoEndpoint( "/user" )
                                        .authorizationEndpoint( "/login/oauth2/oidc-client" ) ) )
                        .userInfoEndpoint( userinfo -> userinfo.authenticationProvider( new AuthenticationProvider() {
                    @Override
                    public Authentication authenticate( Authentication authentication ) throws AuthenticationException {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean supports( Class< ? > authentication ) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } ) )); // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0

        return http.build();
```